# Два массива с одинаковым количеством элементов дают разный результат при прохождении через функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вам будет дан массив целых чисел. Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы взять этот массив и найти индекс N, где сумма целых чисел слева от N равна сумме целых чисел справа от N. Если такого индекса нет, верните -1.

```py
def find_even_index(arr):
    if [arr.index(i)  for i in arr if sum(arr[arr.index(i) + 1 :]) == sum(arr[0 : arr.index(i)])]:
        return [arr.index(i)  for i in arr if sum(arr[arr.index(i) + 1 :]) == sum(arr[0 : arr.index(i)])][0]

    else:
        return -1
```

вызов функции `find_even_index([1,2,3,4,3,2,1])` возвращает `3`
А вызов функция `find_even_index([20,10,30,10,10,15,35])` возвращает `-1`
, хотя они одинаковые по количеству элементов и нахождению элемента для вывода

Comment: Проблема в том, что `arr.index` возвращает индекс первого вхождения 10 в массив: то есть 1, а не 3, как вы ожидаете. Чтобы это исправить перебирайте сразу индексы, а не значения массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А давайте посмотрим, что вы вообще перебираете в цикле. Для этого сделаем вместо вашей функции заглушку, которая будет просто печатать перебираемые значения `i` и `arr.index(i)`:

```
def find_even_index(arr):
    [print(f'i = {i}, arr.index(i) = {arr.index(i)}')  for i in arr]

find_even_index([1,2,3,4,3,2,1])
print('-' * 24)
find_even_index([20,10,30,10,10,15,35])
```

Вывод:

```
i = 1, arr.index(i) = 0
i = 2, arr.index(i) = 1
i = 3, arr.index(i) = 2
i = 4, arr.index(i) = 3 <-- Повезло, что элемент 4 в списке только один
i = 3, arr.index(i) = 2
i = 2, arr.index(i) = 1
i = 1, arr.index(i) = 0
------------------------
i = 20, arr.index(i) = 0
i = 10, arr.index(i) = 1
i = 30, arr.index(i) = 2
i = 10, arr.index(i) = 1 <-- А вот тут вам не повезло (((
i = 10, arr.index(i) = 1
i = 15, arr.index(i) = 5
i = 35, arr.index(i) = 6
```

Как можно видеть, в `i` вы перебираете значения из списка. А `arr.index(i)` вам даёт **индекс первого элемента списка, совпадающего с искомым**. И в первом списке вам очень повезло, что средний элемент списка в нём не повторяется, поэтому метод `arr.index(i)` вам выдал настоящий индекс элемента в массиве. А вот во втором случае, поскольку элементы `10` в списке повторяются, на той итерации, где вы хотели бы видеть индекс `3` вы видите индекс `1`. А индекс `3` вы в итоге вообще не перебираете и не проверяете.

Так что перебирать индексы списка лучше стандартным образом. Так:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    # в i - индекс
    # в arr[i] - элемент списка
```

Или можно ещё так:

```
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    # в i - индекс
    # в x - элемент списка
```

Comment: боже, как я глуп, в упор этого не видел, спасибо огромное!